# Time Difference between per person between consecutive rows

Tags: mysql, sql, split, strsplit, date-difference

I have some data which (broadly speaking) consist of following fields:

```
Person  TaskID   Start_time                      End_time
Alpha   1       'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:10:03 GMT' 'Wed. 18 Oct 2017 10:10:36 GMT'
Alpha   2       'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:11:16 GMT' 'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:11:28 GMT'
Beta    1       'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:12:03 GMT' 'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:12:49 GMT'
Alpha   3       'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:12:03 GMT' 'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:13:13 GMT'
Gamma   1       'Fri, 27 Oct 2017 22:57:12 GMT' 'Sat, 28 Oct 2017 02:00:54 GMT'
Beta    2       'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:13:40 GMT' 'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:14:03 GMT'
```

For this data, my required output is something like:

```
Person  TaskID Time_between_attempts
Alpha   1      NULL      ['Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:10:03 GMT' - NULL]
Alpha   2      0:00:40   ['Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:11:16 GMT' -'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:10:36 GMT']
Beta    1      NULL      ['Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:12:03 GMT' - NULL]
Alpha   3      0:00:35   ['Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:12:03 GMT' -'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:11:28 GMT']
Gamma   1      NULL      ['Fri, 27 Oct 2017 22:57:12 GMT' - NULL]
Beta    2      0:00:51   ['Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:13:40 GMT' -'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 10:12:49 GMT']
```

My requirements are as below:

a. For a given person (Alpha, Beta or Gamma), the first occurrence of the variable 'time_between_attempts' would be zero/NULL - in the example I have shown it as NULL.

b. The second (and the subsequent) times, the same person appears will have a non NULL or non-zero 'time_between_attempts'. This variable is calculated by taking the difference between the ending time of the previous task and the starting time of the next task.

I have following question in this regard:

1. How to write a SQL script which can help me achieve the desired output?

Please note that the TaskID is written as integer just for simplification. In the original data, TaskID is complicated and consists of non-continuous strings as:

```
'q:1392763916495:441',
'q:1392763916495:436'
```

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can use `lag()` and `timestampdiff()` for the calculation.  Assuming your value is a real date/time or timestamp, then you can easily calculate the value in seconds:

```
select t.*,
       timestampdiff(start_time,
                     lag(end_time) over (partition by person_id order by start_time)
                     seconds
                    )
from t;
```

If the values are stored as string, fix the data!  In the meantime, you can use `str_to_date()` in the function.

To get this as a time value:

```
select t.*,
       (time(0) +
        interval timestampdiff(start_time,
                               lag(end_time) over (partition by person_id order by start_time)
                               seconds
                              ) second
       )
from t;
```

Comment: @Gordon
I am unable to run this query. There is an error message:

"Select" is no valid input at this position for this server version, expecting: '(', WITH.....

I am working in mysql workbench 8.0.

Comment: @Sadiaz . . . There is only one `select` in this answer and it is at the beginning of the query.  There should not be a problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , For some reason the code is not working. I am getting following error message:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Start_Time,     lag(End_Time) over (partition by userId order by Start_Time)    ' at line 2

The actual code is:

select 
 timestampdiff(Start_Time, 
        lag(End_Time) over (partition by userId order by Start_Time) 
        seconds
        )
    from int_stellar t;

Comment: @Sadiaz . . . What version of *MySQL* are you using?  The version of workbench is not relevant.

Comment: It is MySQL Server 5.7

Answer (score 1):

Using self Join() method.

```
    SELECT a.person, 
            a.taskid, 
            TIMEDIFF (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(a.Start_time, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') ,DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(b.End_time, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') ) as Time_between_attempts,
            a.Start_time,
            b.End_time

        FROM   test a 
            LEFT JOIN test b 
                    ON a.person = b.person 
                        AND a.taskid = b.taskid + 1 
        ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

But this will ignore timezone.

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution, I have updated my question a bit, could you kindly assist me further on this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how this code works? I am having difficulty in understanding the Join part and where/why you ordered by 1,2?